# Focal Length of Camera View according to Distance

Tags: ios, frame, pixel, cgrectmake

I'm working on an app related to Augmented Reality. It has a gallery that let you select the picture and frame and then a Live Camera Preview shows you how it'll look on your wall. In this live preview use set its distance from wall i.e. `1 meters to 6 meters` and the picture adjusts accordingly and shows in the live camera view. For now I'm using the assumed values like:

```
case 1:
self.imageObject.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageObject.frame.origin.x , self.imageObject.frame.origin.y, 180, 180);            
break;
```

Suppose if the initial size of all the images is `200x200` pixels so what will be the formula from which I can get the exact value that if frame size is `200x200` at `1m` and when it taps `2m` the size changes to the exact 2m value of frame just like a real focal value. Its like distance to pixels conversion what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenseq.html) might help you.
What you need to do is you should know the camera focal length of iPhone camera. It'll be different for 5s, 6 or 6 plus. For a lens of focal length `f` corresponding to lens power `P` an object distance of `o` will produce an image at `i` The linear magnification will be `M`. The formula is `1/object distance + 1/image distance = 1/focal length`. Visit the link to have a more clear idea.